# Global Event Handler window.onload

Tags: javascript

Can I implant global `eventHandler` onload within the `<head>` element?

```
window.onload = function(){ document.write(new Date())};
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use a script tag instead of a code tag.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do here. Are you wanting it to execute your function on firing page onload handler?